# How to read child JSON directly into a collection?

Tags: c#, json

I am getting some data from 2 sources. one of which is sending the required data as a child json.

```
"Shifts": [
        {
            "Shift": {
                "ShiftID": 126604,
                "Name": "Volunteers - High Intensity",
                "Description": "sfsd",
                "Venue": "",
                "StartDateTime": "2014-01-28T12:00:00",
                "EndDateTime": "2014-01-28T16:30:00",
                "LocationN": "0.0",
                "LocationE": "0.0"
            }
        }
]
```

one level deep as compare to other source:

```
"Shifts": [
            {
                    "ShiftID": 126604,
                    "Name": "Volunteers - High Intensity",
                    "Description": "sfsd",
                    "Venue": "",
                    "StartDateTime": "2014-01-28T12:00:00",
                    "EndDateTime": "2014-01-28T16:30:00",
                    "LocationN": "0.0",
                    "LocationE": "0.0"
            }
    ]
```

which i was reading through this code:

```
var shiftProperty = json.GetValue("Shifts");
                        if (shiftProperty != null)
                        {
                            ObservableCollection<Shift> shift = new ObservableCollection<Shift>();
                            MemoryStream memorystream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(shiftProperty.ToString()));
                            DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(shift.GetType());
                            shift = serializer.ReadObject(memorystream) as ObservableCollection<Shift>;
                            App.RootFrame.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                            {
                                Shifts = shift;
                            });
                        }
```

how can i read the data of 1st format in the same way I am reading for 2nd format?

Comment: I think you can get it if you create an object, something like `ShiftContainer` that has one member of type `Shift` and named `Shift` and then deserialize the JSON string into a `ShiftContainer` for the first type of JSON listed.

Comment: Have you tried using JToken.Parse and SelectToken methods ? http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SelectToken.htm

Comment: JSON seems to be invalid, you missing opening and closing {}

Answer (score 0):

```
{
"Shifts": [
    {
        "Shift": {
            "ShiftID": 126604,
            "Name": "Volunteers - High Intensity",
            "Description": "sfsd",
            "Venue": "",
            "StartDateTime": "2014-01-28T12:00:00",
            "EndDateTime": "2014-01-28T16:30:00",
            "LocationN": "0.0",
            "LocationE": "0.0"
        }
    }
]
}


public class Shift2
{
    public int ShiftID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Venue { get; set; }
    public string StartDateTime { get; set; }
    public string EndDateTime { get; set; }
    public string LocationN { get; set; }
    public string LocationE { get; set; }
}

public class Shift
{
    public Shift2 Shift { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Shift> Shifts { get; set; }
}
```

Now just use deserialization, download the assembly. I would advise http://james.newtonking.com/json

To create a C# class representation of your JSON, you can use http://json2csharp.com/